# KafkaConsumer class usage?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am learning KafkaConsumer and have a question in line 3

```
1.from kafka import KafkaConsumer
2.consumer = KafkaConsumer(arglist)
3.for message in consumer
```

I know "for ... in ..." statement. This for loop is used to parse element of collection. So here consumer object can be a collection ?? I looked up in  https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python. However no "collection" thing in KafkaConsume implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, you can iterate over an object as long as it implements/defines the `__iter__` method. This is not limited to collection! Here is a basic example on how to create an *iterable object*:

```
class SimpleExample():

    def __iter__(self):
        i = 0
        while i < 10:
            yield i*2 
            i+=1


se = SimpleExample()
for i in se:
    print(i)
```

This will print `0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18` and exit the loop.

Back to the kafka consumer, `SimpleConsumer` defines such a method in [`simple.py`, line 346](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/consumer/simple.py). This is why you can use the `for .. in` syntax over it.